# How to write after Insert Trigger, when we are comparing 2 Objects

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to sales force and stuck in a trigger logic.

There are 2 objects : `My_Object__c` and `My_Object_Config__c`. Both objects have a common field : `MPG_Code__c`.

My requirement is to write an after insert trigger on My_Object__c that will insert a new record in My_Object_Config__c, if the MPG_Code__c is not in My_Object_Config__c.

```
Trigger MyObject_AfterInsert on My_Object__c (After Insert) {
   MyObjectTriggerUtil.UpdateCode (Trigger.new, null);

}

Public class MyObjectTriggerUtil {

   public static void UpdateCode (List<My_Object__c>, Map<Id, My_Object__c) {

      // TO DO

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you :

```
Map<String, Boolean> checkMap = new Map<String, Boolean>();

for(My_Object__c mo : trigger.new){
    if(checkMap.keySet().contains(mo.MPG_Code__c)){
        throw new myException('duplicated value in trigger list' );
    }
    else{
        checkMap.put(mo.MPG_Code__c, true);
    }
}

for( My_Object_Config__c moc : [SELECT Id 
                                FROM  My_Object_Config__c 
                                WHERE MPG_Code__c IN : checkMap.keySet() ]){
    checkMap.put(mo.MPG_Code__c, false);
}

My_Object_Config__c[] mocs = new My_Object_Config__c[]{};
for(String mapKey : checkMap.keySet()){
    if(checkMap.get(mapKey)){
        mocs.add(new My_Object_Config__c(Name = mapKey, 
                                         MPG_Code__c = mapKey));
    }
}

insert mocs;
```

myException - this is custom exception class.

/** It may cause sme errors - as it was written in NotePad++ **/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the use case correctly, then I think something like this will work for you.

```
Trigger MyObject_AfterInsert on My_Object__c (After Insert) { 

    MyObjectTriggerUtil.UpdateCode(Trigger.new);

}

Public class MyObjectTriggerUtil {

    public static void UpdateCode (List<My_Object__c> myList){

        set<string> mpgCodes = new set<string>();
        for(My_Object__c obj : myList) {
            mpgCodes.add(obj.MPG_Code__c);
        }
        mpgCodes.remove(null);

        list<My_Object_Config__c> configList = [Select Id, MPG_Code__c From My_Object_Config__c Where MPG_Code__c In : mpgCodes ];

        map<string,My_Object_Config__c> code2ConfigMap = new map<string,My_Object_Config__c>();

        for(My_Object_Config__c config : configList) {
            code2ConfigMap.put(config.MPG_Code__c, config);
        }

        list<My_Object_Config__c> configs2Add = new list<My_Object_Config__c>();
        for(My_Object__c obj : myList) {
            if(!code2ConfigMap.containsKey(obj.MPG_Code__c)) {
                configs2Add.add(new My_Object_Config__c(Name = 'Your Name', MPG_Code__c = obj.MPG_Code__c));
            }
        }

        insert configs2Add;
    } 
}
```